# populating listview when item selected in spinner Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, android-spinner, android-checkbox

I am creating a ListView of type multiple choices (check boxes) as below

```
 var adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice);
                    attendanceListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

now I want to check some checkBoxes when item is selected from spinner

and ListView is populated as

```
adapter.Add("Select All");
                    foreach (var item in studentInformation)
                    {
                        adapter.Add(item.studentName.ToString());
                    }
```

every thing is perfect till here. but now problem arises when selecting item from courseSpinner

```
 private void CourseSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
ListView list = (ListView)sender;
                        for (int count = 0; count < attendanceInformation.Count(); count++)
                    {
                        if (attendanceInformation[i].status == true)
                        {
                            selectedStudents[i] = attendanceInformation[i].studentId;
                            list.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list.SetItemChecked(i, false);
                        }
                    }

}
```

but it throws an exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: in your CourseSpinner_ItemSelected method, can you write in the console the value of "sender.GetType()"?

Answer (score 0):

after some effort I am able to solve the problem by just using

```
ListView list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
```

instead of using

```
ListView list = (ListView)sender;
```